# How to run an @MainActor func synchronously?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I have an `@MainActor` function that I want to run synchronously. So far, I've come up with this:

```swift
    static func runOnMainThreadAndWait<T>(
        action: @MainActor @Sendable () throws -> T
    ) rethrows -> T {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            return try unsafeExecuteWithoutActorChecking(action)
        } else {
            return try DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: action)
        }
    }
    
    @preconcurrency
    private static func unsafeExecuteWithoutActorChecking<T>(
        _ action: () throws -> T
    ) rethrows -> T {
        return try action()
    }
```

This works, but the first case of that `if` statement feels janky, and with `-warn-concurrency` even `unsafeExecuteWithoutActorChecking(_:)` doesn't suffice:

> Converting function value of type '@MainActor @Sendable () throws -> T' to '() throws -> T' loses global actor 'MainActor'

What's the safest way to implement this call?

---

Edit, for more details:

The function is usually called from the main thread -- specifically, when a view is created -- and the return value is needed to render the views. It was originally written under the assumption that this would be the *only* way it was called, so no safety mechanisms were put in place. I have been going back through the code and adding `@MainActor` annotations and similar safety checks where appropriate. Here, I need to support the common case (calling it synchronously while on the main thread) while making the incorrect behavior (running on a background thread) impossible. I added an asynchronous overload that calls `await MainActor.run ...` as a stopgap measure, but most of the time `await`ing it is unnecessary and only adds noise.

I've seen a variation on this solution from before Swift's structured concurrency:

```swift
static func runOnMainThreadSync<T>(action: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        return try action()
    } else {
        return try DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: action)
    }
}
```

and I thought I could just add `@MainActor` to this.

Comment: Could I ask you why do you want something like that? The whole idea seems dangerous.

Comment: @Sulthan I've seen functions like this before, I'm just trying to add the `@MainActor` annotation.

Comment: Two background tasks waiting for each other, that would be normal. A main thread waiting for a background thread or viceversa seems very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Running something in the @MainActor context does *not* mean that you are running on the main thread.

It does mean that your code will run synchronously relative to other code running on the Main Actor, which includes code running in the main thread.  But all that means is that while your code is running in the main actor context, if it's not running on the main thread, then the main thread will be suspended. (no other main actor code will be running in parallel)

So your if check is not just janky, it's bogus.

You don't say much about the calling context where you are trying to run something on the main actor, but the easiest solution is probably to use

```
await MainActor.run {
    ... some code here ...
}
```

Comment: The majority of the time, this function will be called from within a view, so it should already be on the main thread. I did look into using `await MainActor.run` but it ended up being more pain than it was worth -- it was originally written as a synchronous function under the assumption that it would *only* be called on the main thread. Only recently did we encounter a case where that assumption is problematic.

Comment: Also, the documentation for MainActor says it's equivalent to the main dispatch queue, and I've always used `DispatchQueue.main` and "main thread" interchangeably. Is that wrong? If so, that is not well-documented -- the documentation for `DispatchQueue.main` says it is at the very least "associated with" the main thread.

Comment: I've personally not seen `DispatchQueue.main`  run code on a thread other than the main thread, but it might have the same guarantees (that the main thread will be suspended while it runs code.  What I have seen is problems if you try to compare the current queue to the main queue to try and figure out if you are in a main thread context.  You can have queues that target the main queue and when they execute blocks, those blocks might be running in a different _queue_ than the main queue.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I've seen a variation on this solution from before Swift's structured concurrency:
>
> ```swift
> static func runOnMainThreadSync<T>(action: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T >{
>    if Thread.isMainThread {
>        return try action()
>    } else {
>        return try DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: action)
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> and I thought I could just add `@MainActor` to this.

You can (and simplify it significantly):

```swift
extension MainActor {
    @MainActor static func runOnMainThread<T>(action: @MainActor @Sendable () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        try action()
    }
}
```

But I would advise against this. One could use [`MainActor.run`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/run(resulttype:body:)).

Or, even better, we can just mark the methods that must be run on a particular actor, and the compiler will perform compile-time checks (rather than the above run-time checks). If you call it from a context not isolated to the particular actor the compiler will tell you that you have to `await`. And only if you have a series of `await` suspension points to the main actor and would like to wrap that in a single task would you ever need to use `MainActor.run`.

But with Swift concurrency, there is no guessing, like we might have had to do in GCD. Nowadays, this `runOnMainThreadSync` pattern (anti-pattern?) is unnecessary. In Swift concurrency, we are generally explicit about which methods and properties are actor isolated, eliminating the ambiguity.

Comment: A large part of the reason why I was looking for something like this is that, unlike `UIView`/`NSView`, SwiftUI's `View` is not implicitly `@MainActor`. Even though the main actor is described as the "UI Actor" and the views' `body` always seems to be called on the main thread, there's no compile-time guarantee of this. I suppose I could mark the views as `@MainActor`, but it seems odd that I have to.

Comment: You don’t have to mark the whole view, but only the method/property that you want to run on the main actor. Alternatively, I personally keep any complicated logic out of the `View` anyway, e.g. have an `ObservableObject` that has this logic and then make sure to update the `@Published` property on the main actor.